# How to use VFSJFileChooser for accessing the remote computer directory

Tags: java, swing, filesystems, jfilechooser

I want to access the remote computer directory for getting the remote file location. I have googled and came to know that VFSJFilechooser can be use for the same. I am not getting any nice example for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's examples [here](http://vfsjfilechooser.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html) that show how to create, display, check, read, etc.

Edit: *It is only browsing the directory of the local system not for the remote computer.*

You need to specify the [supported file system](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html) for your `FileSystemManager`, for [example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html).

Comment: Thx Catalina for giving the prompt reply. I have already gone through the link you have provided but it is only browsing the directory of the local system not for the remote computer.

Comment: Thx again Catalina for providing the link. I have implemented the same, but when i try to connect to the remote computer by clicking on the connection button it is throughing an error, might be i am not providing right path. this is the [link](http://vfsjfilechooser.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) about which i am taking about. would you please tell me how to provide the path.

Comment: Just guessing, maybe a firewall problem?

Comment: Firewall is off and i am able access that system using credetials. I just want to know how to give ftp path.

Comment: There's an example [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html#FTP).

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [VFSJFileChooser](http://vfsjfilechooser.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html), I'm happy to see that many people are using it.

To correct the answer provided, the examples don't really put an emphasis on how to set the actual initial file/directory. A direct answer before giving more details here, the FTP URI syntax is as follow:

```
ftp://usernameIfAny:passwordIfAny@hostname:portIfNotDefault/path/fileOrDir
```

From a user perspective, the best choice is the bookmarks/connections manager available via the side panel. It doesn't expose the inner connections options of protocols though. You can also type directly the URI in the path textfield.

From a developer perspective, as pointed in the previous answer, you'll need to use the [VFS API with the appropriate syntax](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html) accordingly to the protocol that you're using.

```
FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject jarFile = fsManager.resolveFile( "jar:lib/aJarFile.jar" );
```

Once you set the selected file or directory (Syntax similar to JFileChooser), you can retrieve the user selection via the **getSelectedFile**.

If the connection seems to be freezing, check your server configuration. From what I recall, passive mode might be on by default for FTP but *I'm not 100% sure*.

Comment: I am using this tutorial : http://vfsjfilechooser.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html . But I am facing error in this line . final FileObject aFileObject = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); The error is : Referenced method uses a type which is not available: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject

Answer (score 0):

This is a rare error that is only due to a corrupted cache of your IDE.
Hope this helps for other people.